# How to adjust opacity value incrementally for each row as the rows descend in CSS Grid layout using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out a way to target each row in my layout and darken them incrementally as the rows descend. By darken I'm referencing in the context of changing the opacity value. What would be the best approach with my current implementation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To clarify, the top row would the lightest opacity/rgba value and bottom row would be the full color.

My code

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const colors = [
  "#443737",
  "#272121",
  "#ff0000",
  "#ff4d00",
  "#1a1a2e",
  "#16213e",
  "#0f3460",
  "#e94560",
  "#d789d7",
  "#9d65c9",
  "#5d54a4",
  "#2a3d66",
  "#d54062",
  "#ffa36c",
  "#ebdc87",
  "#799351",
];

function createGrid(rows, cols, columnColors) {
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", rows);
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-cols", cols);

  for (i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) {
    const square = document.createElement("div");
    square.style.backgroundColor = columnColors[i % cols];
    container.appendChild(square).className = "grid-item";
  }
}

createGrid(16, 16, colors);
```

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

[image: example of code]

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean by 'darken' (some of the squares are dark already so I'm not sure what effect you want)? Is this just to be visual (which perhaps could be done by an overlay) or would it matter if the background-color in the squares was changed?

Comment: Thank you for you response. Changing the opacity/rgba value. So starting with lightest opacity on top row then getting darker as it descends with the last row being the full solid color.

Comment: Replace `square.style.backgroundColor = columnColors[i % cols];` with `square.style.backgroundColor = columnColors[Math.floor(i/cols)];` for starters.
Set `colors` to actually be light to dark...

Comment: Approximate sorting of colors from light to dark:
`colors.sort((a,b)=>
  parseInt(a.slice(1,3),16)+parseInt(a.slice(3,5),16)+parseInt(a.slice(5,7),16)
  >
  parseInt(b.slice(1,3),16)+parseInt(b.slice(3,5),16)+parseInt(b.slice(5,7),16)
  ?-1
  :1
)`

Comment: Does this work for changing the opacity value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the opacity on each cell as it gets created, just as you do the background-color.

Assuming you want the increase in opacity to be evenly spread down the rows, and assuming you don't want the first row to be completely invisible, changing your loop to something like this will do it:

```
  for (row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
    const square = document.createElement("div");
    square.style.backgroundColor = columnColors[col];
    square.style.opacity=(row+1)/(rows+1);//spread the increase in opacity evenly over the rows
    container.appendChild(square).className = "grid-item";
    }
  }
```

I made it into two loops to make it clearer what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with my suggested editing:
`colors.sort`s by the sum of the "intensity" of each color (RGB).

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const colors = [
  "#443737", "#272121", "#ff0000", "#ff4d00",
  "#1a1a2e", "#16213e", "#0f3460", "#e94560",
  "#d789d7", "#9d65c9", "#5d54a4", "#2a3d66",
  "#d54062", "#ffa36c", "#ebdc87", "#799351"
];

colors.sort((a,b)=>
  parseInt(a.slice(1,3),16)+parseInt(a.slice(3,5),16)+parseInt(a.slice(5,7),16)
  >
  parseInt(b.slice(1,3),16)+parseInt(b.slice(3,5),16)+parseInt(b.slice(5,7),16)
  ?-1
  :1
);

function createGrid(rows, cols, columnColors) {
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", rows);
  container.style.setProperty("--grid-cols", cols);

  for (i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) {
    const square = document.createElement("div");
    square.style.backgroundColor = columnColors[Math.floor(i/rows)];
    container.appendChild(square).className = "grid-item";
  }
}

createGrid(16, 16, colors);
```

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```